# Scaled Resolution switching interfering with Terminal startup

Tags: macos, terminal, macbook-pro, resolution

I saved a window group in Terminal and set that as my default startup group in Terminal preferences "On startup open: window group..."

If I then switch my resolution scaling from "More Space" to "Best (Retina)"  all of my terminal windows shrink to fit (and oddly get wider by two columns).

I think application state saving gets in the way because these fat-squat terminal windows are all I get until I resize them all by hand.

Is there any way to get the windows to resize back to full height when switching back to normal resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I did discover a non-ideal solution when I was researching for this question:

If I close all the windows I can then use the Window > Open Window Group command to get back to my nice windows, though the history is emptied out of each window.

I hope someone else is able to answer this question better.